# Help to identify this plant Please

Tags: identification

This was a Halloween plant from Morrisons, it came with a Witch on a stick
and a bow. Nearest i can find is a Flaming Katy but i am not sure.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Yes that's a kalanchoe also known as Flaming Kate.