# Help me identify this flower!

Tags: identification

I got this little dude at jewel earlier, but there was no info on what kind of plant it is. Help please!!

[image: Visual reference]

Comment: A yellow version: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/22873/help-to-identify-this-plant-please/22875#22875

Answer (score 2):

This I believe is Red Kalanchoe Blossfeldiana.  [Kalanchoe blossfeldiana](http://pics.davesgarden.com/pics/2005/05/18/WillowWasp/a1b22c.jpg)

[Poisonous for cats and dogs](http://www.petpoisonhelpline.com/poison/kalanchoe/)

[kalanchoe care](http://www.krismers.com/Kalanchoe_care.pdf)

Comment: Stormy, that's a duplicate ;-)

Comment: huh?  Hey, I've got family here and just thought I'd run the computer and slide shows...what is a duplicate?  What did I miss?